# output redirection not happening completely

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bash-scripting

I am running the following command on ubuntu 12.04 bash shell:

```
hping3 -S -p 80 -c 30 www.google.com >> outputfile.txt
```

But the problem is that this leaves some lines in the end and doesn't copy in the file.
I even tried

```
hping3 -S -p 80 -c 30 www.google.com >> outputfile.txt 2>&1
```

It also gives same problem. However this works perfect:

```
ping -c 30 www.google.com >> outputfile.txt
```

Any idea about what I might be missing?

Comment: The second command works for me under bash 4.2.37(1)-release with hping 3.0.0-alpha-1. The only weird thing I notice is that output from standard error (2>) is written before the standard out (1>file or >file) in the specified redirection file. This is weird because the standard error output appears after standard out when run on a terminal without any redirection. You may want to try something like: hping (...) 2>/tmp/moo.2 1>/tmp/moo.1 ; cat /tmp/moo.1 /tmp/moo.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write standard error and standard out to separate files and concatenate them afterwards. Also send the maintainer of this software a mail and ask him kindly to change the app to work like everyone expects.